# Laravel how to create areas

Tags: laravel

I am mentioning areas because I have worked with ASP .NET Core before and i can separate my application structure by some feature or department. Each one could have it's own controllers and layouts, etc...

One of the projects i am working on, has a requirement where I will have to replicate the whole app and just change the content.

Right now the main layout is like this

```
views 
    home
        index
    layouts
        navbar
        footer
        ...
```

Comment: Laravel does not have restrictions to implement similar directory structures, be it in views controllers or apps. You should be fine as long as you have proper namespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this within the core folder structure of Laravel.

Let's say you have two areas: `Admin` and `Guest` for example.

You could separate the two at the top level of the `app` directory. And then replicate the typical Laravel folder structure in each.

```
app
   admin
        Http
            Controllers
            Middleware
            ...
        Models
        ...
   guest
        Http
            Controllers
            Middleware
            ...
        Models
        ...
```

Then in the resources folder you can match the separation of views:

```
resources
    views
        admin
            layouts
                admin.blade.php
            index.blade.php
        guest
            layouts
                admin.blade.php
            index.blade.php
```

Then to call your views from your controllers use the dot syntax.

```
view('admin.index')
```

One thing to be careful of this way is that you may need to share models between the two areas like `User` so you would have to manage a 'global' 'area' too.
Just make sure you follow correct namespacing and class importing and you'll be fine.

The other way, which I personally prefer, is to separate things within the existing folder structure. For example your controllers would be in:

```
app
    Http
        Controllers
            Admin
                DashboardController.php
            Guest
                 WelcomeController.php
```

Again you can separate the views in the same way.

You could go a step further and separate your routes files by mapping new routes files in your `RouteServiceProvider`

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapAdminRoutes();

    $this->mapGuestRoutes();
}

/**
 * Define the "admin" routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('admin')
        ->middleware('admin')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

In the end the separation is only for your own benefit as ultimately any class can be imported from any one 'area' to any other and controllers can render views from any 'area' within your resources folder.
It's just a question of how you want to organise things.